# Shortcut to go to next table cell in table in Pages

Tags: macos, keyboard, pages

In Numbers, it is possible to go to the cell below the cell you are currently in by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In a table in Pages, it seems as though pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> simply makes a new line in the table cell. Additionally, pressing the arrow keys only move the text insertion cursor and pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>⌘ Enter</kbd> does deselect the current cell and keep the entered text in it, but it doesn't automatically go to the next cell.

Is there a way (like there is in Numbers) to go to the next cell in a table in Pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**<kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd><kbd>↩︎ enter/return</kbd>** will always move down a cell.

---

The down <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow key will move you down a cell when

- not editing the contents of the cell
  (i.e. the cell is selected but the insertion point is not within the cell), or
- the insertion point is on the last line of the text content of the cell

If your insertion point is on another line of the cell, either

- keep pressing <kbd>↓</kbd> until you get to the bottom line (then another press will jump cell), or
- press <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd><kbd>↩︎enter/return</kbd> first to acknowledge cell contents and jump out of the cell, then <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one go? In Number it seems as though pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> both acknowledges the contents *and* puts you in edit mode in the next cell.

Comment: @Skeleton Yes, see edit